# How to Detect Signs "?" In a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example a div tag url added.

```
<div id="uri_1">www.sitename.com</div>
<div id="uri_2">www.sitename.com/?utm_source</div>
```

How do I know whether a url is plain or there is a "`?`" behind the domain.
I want to make use jQuery / Javascript is also allowed.

Less is more, I need code like this:

```
<script>
var uri_1 = $('#uri_1').html();
var uri_2 = $('#uri_2').html();

// alert();
// uri_1 do not wear pins "?"
// uri_2 there is a sign "?"
</script>
```

Sorry if my question is difficult to understand, but I really need your help. Thanks.

Comment: `uri_2.includes('?')` or `uri_2.indexOf('?') > -1`

Comment: how the full code?

Comment: @dBoys you should use `.text()` instead of `.html()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`url.indexOf("?")` will give position of `?` in the string. As a default value, it returns `-1` if value does not exists. So if `.indexOf` returns anything other that `-1`, this means that value exists in your string.

```
var url = "your url";
if (url.indexOf("?") == -1) {
  alert("? does not exist in this url");
} else {
  alert("? is exist in this url");
}
```

Comment: what explanation you want ...

Comment: check updated answer

Answer (score 1):

`$("#uri_1").html().indexOf("?") != -1`

*EDIT*: Basically the OP wants to know if there exists a `?` in its HTML, so we just have to get the index of that char. `-1` is the value that [`indexOf()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) returns if there was no coincidence in the given string. So, `if ($("#uri_1").html().indexOf("?") != -1)` would tell us that there exists a `?` in the string.

Comment: And why would this solve? Please add explanation. You are answering for readers and not just for OP

Comment: Ah, sorry, editing.